# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.In react

Tags: react-native

```
  await fetch('http://localhost:9001/api/order', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      'customerName': username.split("@")[0],
      'email': username,
      'phoneNumber': '9988776655',
      'amount': location.state.price.toString()
    })
  }).then(function (response, err) {
    console.log(response,'  <<<< >>>>  ', err)
  })
```

I want to send these data from react to Spring Boot, but getting error saying that:
"Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:9001/api/order' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I have done everything from Spring Boot side, but still not resolved.

Edit: Solved by changing a code in spring Boot WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Comment: CORS policies are managed server side, not in react. So your issue comes from your misconfigured backend

Comment: yes I solved this issue after a change in spring boot, thanks for your response